# iOS/Swift/Storyboard: Add PageViewController using only *part* of screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

New to Swift.  I've seen many tutorials on using PageViewController, but they always have the Page View taking up the whole screen.

I'm trying to implement a Page View functionality in only PART of my app, not the entire screen, so that other "static" elements (e.g. a ToolBar) can remain.  Something that would look kinda like this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QVt6.jpg  --- (Need more rep. before embedding images)

...where swiping will cause different images to appear as seen in various PageViewController tutorials (e.g. http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/).

When I start with a Single View Application, I go to Storyboard and try to drag a "Page View Controller" from the Object Library into the ViewController frame, it just "bounces back", i.e. it won't let me add the Page View Controller.

Now, if I add the Page View Controller to the white space around the other View Controller, then this gets back to the tutorials where the PageViewController takes up the entire screen and I don't want that.

How does one achieve this?

Thanks.

Sorry if this is a dupe but I have tried & failed to find anything that answers my question directly.  The closest are [Implement PageViewController in TableViewController details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547555/implement-pageviewcontroller-in-tableviewcontroller-details) or [Adding a UIPageViewController to a subview, subview only shows edge of pageContentview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695751/adding-a-uipageviewcontroller-to-a-subview-subview-only-shows-edge-of-pageconte), but these are not similar enough for me to comprehend, plus they're in Objective C which I've not yet learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I start with a Single View Application, I go to Storyboard and try to drag a "Page View Controller" from the Object Library into the ViewController frame, it just "bounces back", i.e. it won't let me add the Page View Controller.

A page view controller is a view controller. Thus, to make its view occupy only part of the screen, you must obey the rules for view controllers in general: you need a custom parent view controller, and the page view controller must be its child view controller — and you must do the elaborate dance that this entails when you create the child and put its view into the interface.

To get the storyboard to do the dance for you, use a Container View and hook it by its embed segue to the page view controller:

[image]

[image]

(Still, in my opinion it is always better to learn to do the dance manually, in code, yourself.)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't seem to "hook it by its embed segue to the page view controller" When I add a Container it creates a new ViewController which is connected by an Embed segue. I can't re-route this Embed segue to my PageViewController:  I've tried right-clicking, command-clicking, going to Attributes Inspector, looking at Connections (can't edit), deleting it and re-adding it... I'm looking at tutorial (http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers), but controll-dragging doesn't produce an "embed" option.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm adding some screen shots to my answer.

Comment: Okay, I've added screen shots. Still, in my opinion it is always better to learn to do the dance manually, in code, yourself. My book teaches it to you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: Ah!  Added my comment before you added screen shots.  That helps, and it works!   Ok, back to the grindstone!  Thanks.  Had not occurred to me to control-drag on the left where the text is, was control-dragging between the "pictures" and it wasn't giving me an embed option, only "Manual"...

Comment: You don't "reconnect" it. Just delete the unwanted view controller and drag out a new embed segue from the container view to the page view controller as shown by my illustrations.

Comment: "was control-dragging between the pictures and it wasn't giving me an embed option, only Manual" No, you can do it that way too. One of the options _is_ an embed segue. It sounds to me like you were not dragging from _the container view_ to the page view controller.